# How to generate google-services.json for existing Google Android project?

Tags: android, google-api, google-cloud-messaging

In the following website, when registering for Android GCM:
https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=signin&cntapp=Default%20Demo%20App&cntpkg=com.google.samples.quickstart.signin&cnturl=https:%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fidentity%2Fsign-in%2Fandroid%2Fstart%3Fconfigured%3Dtrue&cntlbl=Continue%20with%20Try%20Sign-In

The google-services.json file is generated here. This is required on the client side.

How can we generate this file for **existing** Google Android project?

Comment: you have to add the android projects to the google cloud developer console

Comment: In the google developer console, I have an existing project already, but can't seem to find how to generate google-services.json for this particular project. Is this possible? I would like to not create a *new* project in order to generate a google-services.json

Comment: Have you checked the [Get a configuration file](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#get-config) part of the GCM for Android documentation? Once done, you move the file to the `app/` folder in which the Google Play Service plugin of Gradle parses the config information from the file.

Comment: @adjuremods Of course we read, this approach create a new project, this is not what we seek. How to create the JSON file to an existing project? that is the question, tks

Comment: @android-user You got a solution?

Comment: @android-user if you found any solutions please let us know.

Comment: I think it is possible to edit the json file with info about current Project - I will research...

Comment: @android-user Do you have found any solution in the meantime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this same problem today, very frustrating, but I finally found something that worked for me.

The problem with the page you referenced is that your existing projects do not show up in the "Create or Choose an App" dropdown.  I had this same issue, even when it showed that I was logged into my google developer account.

I think there is a problem with the session on this page, so it doesn't load your projects.  I was able to get it to work when accessing the page through the console help feature.

This is how I did it.  It seems illogical, but stick with me:

1. Sign out of google developer console
2. Sign in to https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard
3. In the top blue bar, "select a project" dropdown, select the project for which you want to generate the json file.
4. In the top blue bar, click the Help icon. A Console Help feature will pop up.
5. Type "google-services.json" into the Help feature search bar and press enter.
6. Click on the help item titled "Set up a GCM Client App on Android"

Now, this is where it starts to seem illogical, because you're going to go to the same pages that didn't work for you before, but stick with me.

7. Scroll down the page a bit and click the blue "GET A CONFIGURATION FILE" button.

This button is going to take you to the exact same page you referenced in your question.  However, your list of current apps should appear in the "Create or Choose and App" dropdown.

This worked for me, I hope it works for you.

WARNING: When I did this, it changed my API Key.  My project number and other info stayed the same, but my API Key changed.  So if you have projects that depend on your existing API key, you'll have to deal with the consequenses.

Comment: is there a way so without affecting my API Key?

Comment: @DeepakNegi You can edit the json file and replace the newly generated API Key with your existing API key

Comment: @JamesWiley "Set up a GCM Client App on Android" does not appear now... They switched some part to firebase. https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#create-an-api-project and https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592?hl=en may help.

Comment: This is deprecated as of now - Google encourages us to use the Firebase console instead

Answer (score 0):

Use existing project's App name (and package name) in the dialog
shown after you click "Get a configuration file" button
 in Google Sign-in for Android / Try Sign-In for Android page.
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start
(This leads to the same link shown in question)

NB
This process creates new API and OAuth keys
and the generated json file uses these keys.
So manual edit may be needed to change keys in json file 
after you've downloaded it.

If API and OAuth keys are exist,
and the key names are same as auto-generated ones
(like "~~ (auto created by Google Service)")
they will be used in the json file.